# Is wait(NULL) well defined?

Tags: c, posix

I've read `man 3p wait`, but what I could only find was this statement:

> In this case, if the value of the argument `stat_loc` is not a null pointer, information shall be stored in the location  pointed to by  `stat_loc`.

I could also find opengroup page on google, but it was almost exactly same with `man 3p wait`.
Where can I find explicit statement that says `wait(NULL)` is well defined?

Comment: That sentence defines the behavior. You can read the "if" as "if and only if", if that helps make it clear.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: "The opengroup page" refers to the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/wait.html), which does purport to define, somewhat formally, how the function shall behave on all conforming systems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you'll find an explicit statement, but this is typical wording for this situation.  If they meant that NULL was not allowed, you would see a statement like "`stat_loc` shall be a non-NULL pointer" or "`stat_loc` shall point to an object..." or "if `stat_loc` is NULL, the behavior is undefined".

In this case, it just means that if you pass a null pointer, the defined behavior is that `wait` just ignores it, and doesn't store that information anywhere at all.

Comment: Or it simply wouldn't mention NULL at all, and then you'd be subject to the rules about not passing null pointers to functions that are not documented to expect them.